# Can I expand arbitrary functinos by the solution of 3-D Laplace eqution?

Tags: polynomials, orthogonality, harmonic-functions

If a function $\Phi$ satisfy

$$
\nabla^2 \Phi(r, \theta, \phi) = 0
$$

then the general solution can be written as

$$
\Phi(r, \theta, \phi) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l (A_l r^l + B_l r^{-l-1}) P_l^m(\cos\theta) e^{\pm i m \phi}
$$

Where $A_l$ and $B_l$ are constants and $P_l^m$ is the associated Legendre polynomial.

Can I use

$$
\sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l (A_l r^l + B_l r^{-l-1}) P_l^m(\cos\theta) e^{\pm i m \phi}
$$

to express arbitrary functions including the functions even not a solution of the Laplace equation?

Comment: No - this can be easily deduced as the $\Delta$ of such a function is zero....

Comment: How to compose a function that cannot be expressed as

$$
\sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l (A_l r^l + B_l r^{-l-1}) P_l^m(\cos\theta) e^{\pm i m \phi}
$$

I tried to analyze Green's function of the 3D Laplace operator.

$$G(\vec{x}, \vec{x'}) = 4\pi \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l} 
\frac{1}{(2l + 1)}\frac{r^l_{\lt}}{r^{l + 1}_{\gt}}
Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)\frac{\left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{r_\lt} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]\left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{r_\gt}{b} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
}{1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}}$$

It can be expressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first comment below the question, the answer is no. For all valid pair of $l$ and $m$ and any constant $A$,

$$
A r^l P_l^m(\cos\theta) e^{\pm i m \phi}
$$

and

$$
A r^{-l-1} P_l^m(\cos\theta) e^{\pm i m \phi}
$$

are the solutions of the Laplace equation

$$
\nabla^2 \Phi(r, \theta, \phi) = 0
$$

This mean if a function $f(r, \theta, \phi)$ can be express as

$$
f(r, \theta, \phi) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l (A_l r^l + B_l r^{-l-1}) P_l^m(\cos\theta) e^{\pm i m \phi}
$$

, $f$ must be a solution of the Laplace equation. To compose a function cannot be expressed as $\sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l (A_l r^l + B_l r^{-l-1}) P_l^m(\cos\theta) e^{\pm i m \phi}$ is trivial.

$$
A r^{l-1} P_l^m(\cos\theta) e^{\pm i m \phi}
$$

is an example.

### About the Green's function

The Green's function of 3-D Laplace operator is

$$
G(\vec{x}, \vec{x'}) = 4\pi \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}  \frac{1}{(2l + 1)}\frac{r^l_{\lt}}{r^{l + 1}_{\gt}} Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)\frac{\left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{r_\lt} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]\left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{r_\gt}{b} \right)^{2l + 1} \right] }{1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}}
$$

$\vec{x}$ and ${x'}$ are $(r, \theta, \phi)$ and $(r', \theta', \phi')$ correspondingly. $r = a$ is the inner boundary surface, and $r = b$ is the outer boundary surface. You can read $G(\vec{x}, \vec{x'})$ as $G(r, \theta, \phi;\ r', \theta', \phi')$. When $|\vec{x}| \lt |\vec{x'}|$, $r_{\lt} = |\vec{x}| = r$ and $r_{\gt} = |\vec{x'}| = r'$. When $|\vec{x}| \ge |\vec{x'}|$, $r_{\gt} = |\vec{x}| = r$ and $r_{\lt} = |\vec{x'}| = r'$.

$$\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
r_{\lt} = |\vec{x}| = r \\
r_{\gt} = |\vec{x'}| = r'
\end{cases}
&& \text{for } |\vec{x}| \lt |\vec{x'}| \\
\begin{cases}
r_{\lt} = |\vec{x'}| = r' \\
r_{\gt} = |\vec{x}| = r
\end{cases}
&& \text{for } |\vec{x}| \ge |\vec{x'}| \\
\end{align*}
$$

For case that $|\vec{x}| \lt |\vec{x'}|$,

$$\begin{align*}
G(\vec{x}, \vec{x'})
&= 4\pi \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}
  \frac{1}{(2l + 1)}
  \frac{r^l_{\lt}}{r^{l + 1}_{\gt}}
  Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
  Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)
  \frac{
    \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{r_\lt} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
    \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{r_\gt}{b} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
  }{
    1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}
  } \\
&= 4\pi \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}
  \frac{1}{(2l + 1)}
  \frac{r^l}{r'^{l + 1}}
  Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
  Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)
  \frac{
    \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{r} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
    \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{r'}{b} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
  }{
    1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}
  } 
  && (r_\lt = r,\ r_\gt = r') \\
&= \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}
  \frac{4 \pi}{(2l + 1)}
  \frac{1}{r'^{l + 1}}
  Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
  \frac{
    \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{r'}{b} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
  }{
    1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}
  }
  r^l
  \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{r} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
  Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi) 
  && (\text{rearrange variables}) \\
&= \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}
  \frac{4 \pi}{(2l + 1)}
  \frac{
    Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
  }{
    1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}
  }
  (-b^{-2l - 1} r'^l + r'^{- l - 1})
  (r^l - a^{2l + 1} r^{-l - 1})
  Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)
  && (\text{rearrange variables}) \\
&= \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}
  C_{lm}
  (-b^{-2l - 1} r'^l + r'^{- l - 1})
  (r^l - a^{2l + 1} r^{-l - 1})
  Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi) 
  && (
    \text{let } C_{lm}
    = \frac{4 \pi}{(2l + 1)}
      \frac{
        Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
      }{
        1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}
      }
  ) \\
\end{align*}$$

We got $A_l = C_{lm}(-b^{-2l - 1} r'^l + r'^{- l - 1})$ and $B_l = -a^{2l + 1} C_{lm}(-b^{-2l - 1} r'^l + r'^{- l - 1})$

For case that $|\vec{x}| \ge |\vec{x'}|$,

$$\begin{align*}
G(\vec{x}, \vec{x'})
&= 4\pi \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}
  \frac{1}{(2l + 1)}
  \frac{r^l_{\lt}}{r^{l + 1}_{\gt}}
  Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
  Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)
  \frac{
    \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{r_\lt} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
    \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{r_\gt}{b} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
  }{
    1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}
  } \\
&= 4\pi \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}
  \frac{1}{(2l + 1)}
  \frac{r'^l}{r^{l + 1}}
  Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
  Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)
  \frac{
    \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{r'} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
    \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{r}{b} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
  }{
    1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}
  } 
  && (r_\lt = r',\ r_\gt = r) \\
&= \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}
  \frac{4 \pi}{(2l + 1)}
  r'^l
  Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
  \frac{
    \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{r'} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
  }{
    1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}
  }
  r^{-l - 1}
  \left[ 1 - \left( \dfrac{r}{b} \right)^{2l + 1} \right]
  Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi) 
  && (\text{rearrange variables}) \\
&= \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}
  \frac{4 \pi}{(2l + 1)}
  \frac{
    Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
  }{
    1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}
  }
  (r'^l - a^{2l + 1} r'^{- l - 1})
  (-b^{-2l - 1} r^l + r^{-l - 1})
  Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)
  && (\text{rearrange variables}) \\
&= \sum^\infty_{l = 0} \sum^l_{m = -l}
  C_{lm}
  (r'^l - a^{2l + 1} r'^{- l - 1})
  (-b^{-2l - 1} r^l + r^{-l - 1})
  Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi) 
  && (
    \text{let } C_{lm}
    = \frac{4 \pi}{(2l + 1)}
      \frac{
        Y^*_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
      }{
        1 - \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)^{2l + 1}
      }
  ) \\
\end{align*}$$

We got $A_l = -b^{-2l - 1} C_{lm} (r'^l - a^{2l + 1} r'^{- l - 1})$ and $B_l = C_{lm} (r'^l - a^{2l + 1} r'^{- l - 1})$

After comparing $A$ and $B$ from the two cases, we find that only when

$$
\frac{a^{2l + 1}}{b^{2l + 1}} = 1 \Rightarrow a = b
$$

$G(\vec{x}, \vec{x'})$ can be expressed as $\sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l (A_l r^l + B_l r^{-l-1}) P_l^m(\cos\theta) e^{\pm i m \phi}$. However, the interest area also becomes zero when $a = b$ and the Green's function becomes meaningless. If $a \lt b$, $A_l$ and $B_l$ will be functions of $r$ and have a jump at $r'$.